# Como usar o conceito de ponteiro em php?

Tags: php, ponteiro

To aprendendo sobre ponteiro em linguagem C e já sei com usar. Acredito que a forma de usar ponteiro em php seja a mesma em C. Mas como faço declaração de ponteiro em php?

Comment: Em php pode-se chamar de referencias, porem é muito dificil o seu uso veja um post sobre o assunto, http://www.vivaolinux.com.br/artigo/Referencias-ou-ponteiros-em-PHP

Comment: É importante notar que não existe o conceito de ponteiro em PHP. Pelo menos não na linguagem de forma que o programador possa usar. Como já foi dito na resposta, só existem referências. Claro que internamento o PHP usa ponteiros para realizar suas atividades mas isto é opaco. Ponteiro é algo bem mais poderoso que referência e consequentemente mais complexo e inseguro se não for apropriadamente manipulado.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Em PHP pode ser chamado tanto de ponteiros como referências.

Referências, em PHP, significa acessar o mesmo conteúdo de variável através de vários nomes. Porém é comum ouvir erroneamente a expressão "uso de ponteiros" em PHP, o que por sua vez não chega nem a ser parecido como os ponteiros em C: temos em PHP apelidos numa tabela simbólica (em C endereço de memória).

```
<?php
  $a = &$b;
  // aqui $a e $b apontam para a mesma variável. 
?>
```

> Logo $a e $b são completamente iguais aqui, mas não porque $a está apontando para $b ou vice-versa, mas sim porque $a e $b apontam para o mesmo lugar.
>
> A mesma sintaxe pode ser utilizada com funções que retornam referências e com o operador new (a partir do PHP 4.0.4):
>
> Fonte: http://www.vivaolinux.com.br/artigo/Referencias-ou-ponteiros-em-PHP?pagina=1

Você pode acessar o POST original no site Viva o Linux e conhecer mais sobre o assunto.
http://www.vivaolinux.com.br/artigo/Referencias-ou-ponteiros-em-PHP?pagina=1

Comment: *Viva O Linux..

Comment: Obrigado ZebraDoMal, você poderia ter feito a correção mais eu já fiz.